# Is FatFree or f3 Framework compatible with PHP7?

Tags: fat-free-framework

I've found this Fat-free framework. I it's built-in ORM that can run sql or no-sql with my project's anticipation of adding mongodb in the future along with existing mysql. Despite 55kb size per their website, it has great features, overly simple, clean, and so flexible. However, I googled but cant find anything about php7 compatibility. Even the fat-free's documentation does not mention anything about php7. I'm hoping anyone has an idea?

Comment: I don't think it has been fully tested against PHP7 yet. See also the framework [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/f3-framework/bTv8gmoIJsM/discussion) and Github issues [880](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/880) and [895](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/895).

Comment: I've run it on PH7 RC no Problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I have run Fat-Free 3.5.1 on PHP7 built-in web server without issue thus far.  I will eventually run it on Nginx on Ubuntu and hope it will work fine there as well (hopefully the Nginx reported problem is a non-issue at this time).

Answer (score 0):

Works absolutely brilliant on Apache2, PHP7 and FatFree 3.6